# Logging Hibernate Configuration Details

Tags: hibernate, logging

[Java Persistence in Hibernate](http://www.manning.com/bauer2/) mentions it's possible to modify logging properties to show extra configuration details of Hibernate:

```
Ejb3Configuration:141
- Trying to find persistence unit: helloworld
Ejb3Configuration:150
- Analyse of persistence.xml:
file:/helloworld/build/META-INF/persistence.xml
PersistenceXmlLoader:115
- Persistent Unit name from persistence.xml: helloworld
Ejb3Configuration:359
- Detect class: true; detect hbm: true
```

Below is my `$APP\my-jph-example\src\main\resources\log4j.properties`

```
# direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE}
    %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

#Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout

#Hibernate logging options (INFO only shows startup messages)
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG

#Log JDBC bind parameter runtime arguments
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=INFO
```

Despite the above configuration, I don't see any extra logging details.

Note that I set `org.hibernate` per the Hibernate [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging).

How do I need to modify this `log4j.properties` file to show the extra configuration details of Hibernate? Also, I'm **not** asking about logging SQL statements.

Comment: You reference the 3.3 Hibernate docs.  Is that the version of Hibernate you are using?

Comment: Hi @SteveEbersole. Yes. Looking at my pom.xml, I see `artifactid`: `hibernate-entitymanager` with version:`3.3.2.GA`